# Unable to connect from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 8.1 Pro using PuTTY (SSH 2)

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssh, putty

Disabled the firewall and still unable to connect. I can connect to our Macbooks in the office from my Windows machine using PuTTY SSH but I can't connect to our Windows machines that I installed PuTTY on. I tried both the IP address and host name. I get "Network error: Connection timed out" every time. Every computer, both Mac and Windows, have the same administrator account. I checked running services on these Windows machines and I don't see anything PuTTY or SSH related. Could that be the problem? I figured by installing PuTTY it would automatically set it up for other local PuTTY connections. Did I forget anything?

Comment: PuTTY is a client, not a server. Do you have a server installed on the Windows 8.1 machine to answer your SSH requests? If not, that's why it's not working.

Comment: You write "I checked running services on these Windows machines and I don't see anything PuTTY or SSH related. Could that be the problem? I figured by installing PuTTY it would automatically set it up for other local PuTTY connections. Did I forget anything?"  <---- yeah. and see techie007's comment. There is winsshd, and there is cygwin openssh.   Maybe others too.

Comment: Yup, my fault. Completely assumed an SSH server was included with PuTTY. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two places that may offer you direction.

https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers